# Materialデザインのボタンはどうやって実装したらよいでしょう？

Tags: android, material-design

[Materialデザインガイドライン](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html)に書いてあるようなFloating action button, Raised buttonはどのように実装すれば良いのでしょうか？

Flat buttonはこの二つを入れれば良さそうな気がするのですが…

```
style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
android:textStyle="bold"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Raised buttonは下記で文字と背景色を設定すればいけると思います。

```
style parent="android:Widget.Material.Button"
```

Floating action buttonはライブラリがgithubにありますね
https://github.com/shamanland/floating-action-button

参考：http://qiita.com/pside/items/b99a978b7b0fdbd52468
(ripple effectの解説ですがボタンの作り方が詳しく解説されています。

Answer (score 6):

私も現在 Material デザインの実装を行っています。

[MaterialDesignLibrary](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) というライブラリは FlatButton から SnackBar まで多様な Material デザインをカバーしており、利用や実装方法に非常に参考となります。

簡単な実装ではアイコンを用意し、以下の様なレイアウトを書くだけで可能となります。

**Floating Action Button**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<!-- ... XML CODE -->
<com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFloat
            android:id="@+id/buttonFloat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
            android:background="#1E88E5"
            materialdesign:animate="true"
            materialdesign:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new" />
```

ただ、現在未だ [maven レポジトリに登録されてない](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/issues/1)のでプロジェクトに含めなければいけないのが難点です。